# Read a .txt file in POI

Tags: servlets, apache-poi

Can we read a .txt file using POI.
I am able to read excel and pdf file but when i tried to read a .txt file it is giving me error such as

> java.io.IOException: Unable to read entire header; 41 bytes read;
>   expected 512 bytes

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) works with Microsoft Office file formats, such as .xls or .docx

To process a .txt file, you'll want something like BufferedReader. Just have a look online, you'll find a mind bogglingly large number of tutorials and articles on how to read plain text files with Java.